# Restricted Textinput to numbers, empty textinput results not in a null value but 0?

Tags: actionscript-3, flex3, textinput, restriction

i want to restrict the input to numbers only, but do have a problem for an empty entry:

now accessing like this:

```
var newValue:Number = event.itemRenderer.data[event.dataField]
```

newValue is now for an empty entry not null, but 0...

Comment: First of all, would you mind posting some more code so that we all can have a better look?
Furthermore you are storing the data of your item renderer in a Number, which will automatically default to 0 when a null value is assigned to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use something like:

```
var newValue:Number = event.itemRenderer.data[event.dataField] ? Number(event.itemRenderer.data[event.dataField]) : NaN;
```

And use `NaN` but not `null` for `Number` data type. And you can call `isNaN()` global function to check for `NaN`.